# How to prevent user from leaving a DBGrid's cell depending on it's value

Tags: delphi, validation, delphi-7, tclientdataset, dbgrid

Here's my situation:
I have a task in which I need to make some operations using TClientDataSet's (yes I have to use this specific component). The user will be able to edit the data inside the TClientDataSet, so I'm using a TDBGrid connected to a TDataSource, which is connected to my TClientDataSet.

What I need to do is to prevent the user from leaving the cell (moving the focus to somewhere else in the program) based on it's value. A valid value is a time starting from 00:00 to 23:59. It cannot be empty or have blank characters. I'm using the EditMask property of the TClientDataSet's fields so it's very easy to type straight in the right format.

Example:
If the user typed 29:00 in the cell, and then tries to move to another cell (or another component), I want to be able to stop that, and make him enter some other valid value in the cell (like 15:00), then he can leave it and do something else (like editing another cell).

What are the options to make this kind of validation? I'm using Borland Delphi 7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [TField.OnValidate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Data.DB.TField.OnValidate) event. This is called after the `EditMask` has been validated, but before the data is actually written to the record buffer. This allows you to do more extensive validations after the basic character validation has been done.

The event receives the field being validated in the `Sender` parameter to the `TFieldNotifyEvent`:

```
TFieldNotifyEvent = procedure(Sender: TField) of Object;
```

You can do what you need to do to validate the data in that event, and raise an Exception if the new value does not meet your time span requirements. For instance, the following will raise an exception if less than 2 characters is entered into the field:

```
procedure TForm4.ClientDataSet1ClientDataSet1Field1Validate(Sender: TField);
begin
  if not (Length(Trim(Sender.AsString)) > 1) then
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid length for field content.');
end;
```

An alternative is to use the [TDBGrid.OnColExit](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGrid.OnColExit) event instead, but I prefer to keep the data validation code with the database content more directly instead of tying it to a particular part of the user interface. (Keeping it with the database makes it automatically enforced even when you change your mind later and switch from using a grid to using a separate form for record maintenance, or when you set the field value from code instead of the UI.)

As far as actually validating the data itself, the easiest way is to use [TRegEx](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx) if it's available in the version of Delphi you're using. Something like this expression should work:

```
var
  FoundMatch: Boolean;
  TimeStr: string;
begin
  TimeStr := Sender.AsString;
  FoundMatch := TRegEx.IsMatch(TimeStr,
        '\A([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\z', [roMultiLine]);
  if not FoundMatch then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid time value %s', [TimeStr]);
end;
```

If `TRegEx` isn't available in your version of Delphi, you can find the free, open source `TPerlRegEx` at the [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html) website; it's the code that was used in current Delphi versions in the core of its regular expression support. In that case, this code should work as well:

```
var
    Regex: TPerlRegEx;
    FoundMatch: Boolean;
    TimeStr: string;
begin
  TimeStr := Sender.AsString;
  Regex := TPerlRegEx.Create;
  try
    Regex.RegEx := '\A([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\z';
    Regex.State := [preNotEmpty];
    Regex.Subject := TimeStr;
    FoundMatch := Regex.Match;
    if not FoundMatch then
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid time value %s', [TimeStr]);
  finally
    Regex.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I edited my question with the code I created using the OnValidate method. It's not raising a simple "test" Exception.

Comment: Maybe I'm not handling the Exception properly. Do I have to add any other code to actually make the prevention I want, or just raising that Exception stops any other action being made by the user?

Comment: If you have an EditMask on the field, then `Length` will never be < 1. You need to use `Length(Trim(Sender.AsString))`. See my edit. (The code showing the example of using the regular expression to validate would plug right into that event handler as well.) Raising the exception prevents the field content from being stored. You have to write the code to validate that the time is within the range allowed and raise the exception if it is not; the regex example also demonstrates doing so. Since you've added Delphi 7 in the title, you'll need the TPerlRegEx I linked; example added for that also.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I'm using Delphi 7, so I can't using regex (and I don't think an external library would fit well into the task context (it's basically just a test)).